# String was not recognised as a valid datetime exception

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting an above exception while converting datetime to varchar

```
if (columnDefs[i].IndexOf("Date") > -1)
{
    // Date search
    subQuery += columnDefs[i] + 
                " = '%" + 
                DateTime.Parse(searchValues[i]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + 
                "'" + " and ";
}
```

Comment: Please add the language tag. Also add the stacktrace

Comment: Might want to include a language tag so it gets better coverage.

Comment: It looks like you're building up an SQL query by string concatenation. **Stop** doing that. Pass your datetimes *as* datetimes by using parameters.

Comment: What is the value of `searchValues[i]` exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

When working with SQL do not *hardcode* but *paramterize* queries; assuming that you work with MS SQL which has `@parameter_name` syntax:

```
if (columnDefs[i].IndexOf("Date") >= 0)
{
    // Date search: we a parameter, not its value into the query
    subQuery += $" ({columnDefs[i]} = @prm_{columnDefs[i]}) and ";
}

...

// when executing the query
using (var myQuery = new SqlQuery(subQuery, myConnection)) {
  // we set parameters' values
  for (int i = 0; i < columnDefs.Count(); ++i) {
    if (columnDefs[i].IndexOf("Date") >= 0) {
      //TODO: check the actual parameter value type (SqlDbType.DateTime?) 
      var prm = new SqlParameter($"@prm_{columnDefs[i]}", SqlDbType.DateTime);
      //TODO: check actual string format (d/M/yyyy?)
      prm.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(
         searchValues[i], 
        "d/M/yyyy", 
         CutureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      myQuery.Parameters.Add(prm);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```